# CentOS 8.2 does not boot after updating in 1 Aug 2020

Tags: centos, grub, centos-8

I updated my CentOS 8.2 yesterday (`yum update`), everything was good until a rebooted my system, there was no boot loader! the system get stuck in a black window without showing anything at all.indeed the problem is grub. I tried to re-config my grub (`grub2-mkconfig`) by using CentOS 8.2 rescue mode (booted by the DVD ISO), nothing happened.

information:

- my system is `EFI` (not legacy `BIOS`)
- in the update process both grub and kernel updated as I remember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was resolved. this is [a bug in grub2 security update](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1861977) discovered 2 days ago.

what I did for solving this problem:

1 - use CentOS 8.2 `iso` to boot from and use rescue mode and use `chroot`.

2 - config local repository for `BaseOS` repo using the image

3 - downgrade `grub2` and `shim` packages(`yum downgrade shim-x64 grub2\*`)

4 - done!